# getting error while passing .csv file as an argument in jmeter for Docker

Tags: docker, jmeter

I have to execute multiple .jmx files with .csv file as an argument over docker.

When I execute single file it throws below error (Once this resolve I can further go for multiple files execution)

```
PS C:\Users\user1> docker run --mount type=bind,source="/D:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/",target="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin" justb4/jmeter -Jcsvfile=bin/scripts/env/script1.csv -n -t bin/scripts/jmxs/Testscript1.jmx -l bin/scripts/jmxs/2602202-2.jtl
```

**Error**:

```
 START Running Jmeter on Tue Feb 28 14:47:01 CET 2023
    JVM_ARGS=-Xmn2280m -Xms9120m -Xmx9120m
    jmeter args=-Jdatadir=bin/scripts/env/script1 .csv -n -t bin/scripts/jmxs/Testscript1.jmx -l bin/scripts/jmxs/2602202-2.jtl
    jmeter ALL ARGS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Jdatadir=bin/scripts/env/script1 .csv -n -t bin/scripts/jmxs/Testscript1.jmx -l bin/scripts/jmxs/2602202-2.jtl
    Feb 28, 2023 2:47:02 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
    INFO: Created user preferences directory.
    An error occurred: Unknown arg: .csv
```

**I have tried with**

```
-Jcsvfile=bin/scripts/env/script1.csv
```

**as well as**

```
-Jdatadir=bin/scripts/env/script1.csv
```

Also I have added CSV Data set config > Filename: ${__P(csvfile,)} but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo: an extra space in your command which is causing the error

```
jmeter args=-Jdatadir=bin/scripts/env/script1 .csv 

                                             ^---here
```

remove it and your test should work as expected (assuming that the CSV file exists under the given location).

You can double check the exact full or relative path to your CSV file(s) by connecting to the container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command like this:

```
docker exec -it your-container-name-or-id /bin/bash
```

once done you can locate the file using [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command:

```
find / -type f -name script1.csv
```

and if the file is there - you will see the full path to it. This is the value you should set as the `csvfile` property.

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: I have added double quotes in arguments and its resolved.